# Change Background of Canvas using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am working on a project and had the idea to create a button that would generate a number using Math.floor and Math.random to select an image in an array, and then apply it as a background to my canvas.

I have been fiddling around with changing just the background color before getting images in the code, and I was curious if there is a way to change the background using a JavaScript function. So far the only way I have been able to change the canvas background is by editing the background-color in css, then putting the styles in the head and foregoing the css altogether.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [change background using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497333/change-background-using-javascript) otherwise you can [google it](https://www.google.ie/search?q=Change+Background+of+Canvas+using+JavaScript&oq=Change+Background+of+Canvas+using+JavaScript&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.74892j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: What you're looking for is editing the `style` property of the element - this has the same effect as modifying the CSS file. eg: `myElement.style = "background-color: blue; font-size: 30px;"`

Comment: I know how to change the background by the style element by typing a color, I just am unsure if I can use a JavaScript function in the style property and if I can, how to do so.

Comment: You can easily use `var myBackgroundColor  = '#dd0300'; myElement.style.backgroundColor = myBackgroundColor;`. Wrapping this in a function could be `function changeBG(element, hexcode){ element.style.backgroundColor = hexcode;}` and then use it like `changeBG (document.querySelector('canvas'),'#dd0300')`

Comment: When you say "background" are you talking about the CSS background of the element <canvas> or do you mean that an image should be drawn on your canvas?

Comment: You could always use a `fillRect` in your canvas code which will then fill in the canvas, or use CSS and use the code @somethinghere has provided

Comment: I am talking about the css background, which I know how to change, I am trying to write a JavaScript function to randomly select an image from an array to use as a background

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="700" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000; background:url('newBG.value');">

My newBG.value is from a js function, but I was curious if this can actually work or if I'm just not writing my function correctly

Answer (score 1):

An HTML canvas can be drawn upon, the first image that is drawn on the canvas will be behind the second image. In order to make a canvas have a "background" you should use the draw function to draw the image on x 0 and y 0 with the width and height of the canvas.

See how to use the draw function here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Comment: That is true, although a canvas is transparent by default so it might be easier to use `background-color`. But yeah, I would have suggested this too.